# Encode/Decode JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have action method in my ASP.NET Core razor page returning  `JsonResult`. I am a filling the values in my model form with returned JSON values.

Here is the code.

```cs
var converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userdetails);
return new JsonResult(converted);
```

Now as per security team recommendation they had asked me to encode all dynamic data, regardless of source, before embedding it in output.

Can anyone help? How I encode and later decode in my razor view?

Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* do they mean by "encode"? It sounds like you need to ask your security team for more detailed guidance.

Comment: They had said that it can cause XSS exploit.

Comment: Fully encode all dynamic data, regardless of source, before embedding it in output. It's recommended to use the platform-provided encoding functionality or known security libraries for encoding output.

Comment: That really doesn't explain what they mean, it's just restating it with the extra word "fully". I suggest you provide the JSON you're currently returning, and ask what they want instead. I suspect that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` already does what that want, or can be asked to via serialization options, but it's hard to know without seeing what's expected.